# DatePicker Size in Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I want to make the size of jquery datepicker quite small. The class of the div after inspecting the HTML is ui-datepicker-div. How can I resize it. Right now it's too big. How do I make it small.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.ui-datepicker {
  font-size: smaller;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bznRE/

With jquery

```
$(someSelector).datepicker().css({'font-size' : 'smaller' });
```

Comment: Why stop there? `font-size: xx-small;`

Comment: @Daniel...how do I do this in jquery

Answer (score 3):

```
().css({'font-size' : 'smaller' });
```

It reduces FONT size not the calender size 
I think the question was to reduce the calender size